# Why disconnect from a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

*Background info:* I'm coding with C#, using Microsoft SQL Server for databases.

I didn't find much on Google on the subject, so I'm asking here: should I always close a connection to my database after performing a query?

I'm torn between two solutions (maybe better ones exist...):

- either open the connection before querying, then close it right after the SQL query
- or open the connection at the start of my application, and before each SQL query check if the connection is still up and reopen it if needed.

In the past, I used the first solution but I discovered that opening a new connection can take quite some time (especially over a VPN connection to my LAN opened through 3G), and that it would slow down my application. That's why I decided to go with the second solution (in that case, my connection should be always up if we forget about time-out) and noticed some better performances.

Do I need to close the connection at the end of my application or can I forget about it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you should close your connection after each SQL query. The database connection pool will handle the *physical* network connection, and keep it open for you. You say that you found that opening a connection can take some time - did you find that the application was *really* doing that multiple times?

(I hope your real application won't be talking directly to the database over 3G, btw... presumably this is just for development purposes...)

Comment: For example, I have -let's say- 10 queries at the loading of my application. Connecting, querying, disconnecting 10x will be slower than connecting 1x and querying 10x.
My application is usually used on my work LAN, but sometimes we connect over a VPN by 3G, so queries go through 3G for sure.

Comment: @Leito: You've missed my point. Closing the connection within your code does *not* close the physical connection. The connection pool handles it. However, it sounds like your application quite possibly shouldn't be talking directly to the database in the first place, but should be using some sort of intermediary service...

Comment: My application is directly connecting to the database: I simply use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() after creating the SqlConnection, using the same connection string in my all application.

Answer (score 4):

One important thing to remember is that there is a unique connection pool for each unique connection string you use... so *always* use the same connection string unless you need to connect to a different database (or have unique requirements).

Here is a good document on [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.

Comment: Thanks, that document is quite useful to understand pools and connections management. I do use only one connection string for each database I connect, that's good.

Answer (score 0):

This will heavily depend on how many clients you anticipate will need to connect to the database. Leaving the connection open, could prevent another user from accessing the DB while they wait for an open connection.

Comment: 20 clients max will connect... I guess SQL server can handle 20 connections opened simultaneously, right?

Comment: You can configure within SQL server how many connections to allow. 20 open connections could affect the performance of the server, which may subvert your attempt to increase overall performance though. You'd want to do some load testing before going live.